# SharePoint iLogger from Microsoft.Practices.SharePoint.Common.Logging

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am migrating SP2010 Custom solutions to SP2016. I am getting Security Exception for on

```
private ILogger _logger = Utilities.GetLogger();
```

Any thoughts or workaround in order to write log to ULS as well as to Windows event logs

Thanks in advance.